# insert new record after select text under column

Tags: mysql

i am stuck in between in MYSQL query,
suppose there is a table like this

table old_one

```
| id | name        |  desc |
+----+-------------+-------+
|  1 | joy(ron)    | ALL   | 
+----+-------------+-------+
```

what i want to write a sql query which can create a new row of under bracket data and outside the bracket

table new_one

```
| id | name        |  desc |
+----+-------------+-------+
|  1 | joy         | ALL   | 
+----+-------------+-------+
|  1 | ron         | ALL   | 
+----+-------------+-------+
```

also i am hustling **because name is variable** and this is just the sample. any guess how to implement it?

Comment: Did you mean under a row?

Comment: yes...............

Comment: Add your code for clarification